# Universal splunk forwarder as sidecar not showing internal splunk logs

Tags: kubernetes, logging, splunk, sidecar

I have implemented a sidecar container to forward my main application logs to splunk.
Have used universalsplunkforwarder image.
After I deploy both my main application and forwarder seems up and running. But anyway not recieving any logs in splunk index specified.
To troubleshoot splunkd log or any specific splunk internal logs are not found in /var/log path.
Can someone please help how we enable this splunk internal logs?

piece of deployment.yaml

> 

```
 - name: universalforwarder
>           image: <docker-registry>/splunk/universalforwarder:latest
>           imagePullPolicy: Always
>           env:
>            - name: SPLUNK_START_ARGS
>              value: "--accept-license --answer-yes"
>            - name: SPLUNK_USER
>              value: splunk
>            - name: SPLUNK_PASSWORD
>              value: ****
>            - name: SPLUNK_CMD
>              value: add monitor /var/log
>           resources:
>             limits:
>              memory: "312Mi"
>              cpu: "300m"
>             requests:
>              memory: "80Mi"
>              cpu: "80m"
>           volumeMounts:
>            - name: shared-logs
>              mountPath: /var/log
```

Piece of confgmap.yml

```
outputs.conf: |-
    [tcpout]
    defaultGroup = idxm4d-bigdata


    [tcpout:idxm4d-bigdata]
    server = <servers>
    clientCert = /opt/splunkforwarder/etc/auth/ca.pem
    sslPassword = password
    sslVerifyServerCert = false
  inputs.conf: |-
    [monitor:/bin/streaming/adapters/logs/output.log]


    [default]
    host = localhost
    index = krp_idx


    [monitor:/bin/streaming/adapters/logs/output.log]
    disabled = false
    sourcetype = log4j
    recursive = True
  deploymentclients.conf: |-
    targetUri = <target-uri>
  props.conf: |-
    [default]
    TRANSFORMS-routing=duplicate_data



    [telegraf]
    category = Metrics
    description = Telegraf Metrics
    pulldown_type = 1
    DATETIME_CONFIG =
    NO_BINARY_CHECK = true
    SHOULD_LINEMERGE = true
    disabled = false
    INDEXED_EXTRACTIONS = json
    KV_MODE = none
    TIMESTAMP_FIELDS = time
    TRANSFORMS-routing=duplicate_data
kind: ConfigMap
```

Not able to view splunkd logs to troubleshoot if splunk is able to get the logs or what might be the issue
Thanks

Comment: The Splunk forwarder's internal logs are at /opt/splunkforwarder/var/log/splunk.  If there are problems sending to the indexer then it will be reported there.

Comment: yep, There i am not getting any logs to troubleshoot. That's the issue. @RichG

Comment: If the logs don't exist then the forwarder must not be running.

Comment: Yes, From docker and kubernetes pod (custom execution was executing successfully )(In rancher explicitly if I am starting splunk it is starting.) ...seems env variables are not configured properly. Not sure what exactly has to be changed.

Comment: check wether the splunk is running or not by checking status.  $ docker exec -it -u splunk <container_name/container_id> /bin/bash

Comment: Please make sure that the index= krp_idx is present on your indexer which is defined at below stanza ( [tcpout:idxm4d-bigdata]
    server = <servers>   )